# Error while compiling on a 64-bit machine

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, compilation, 64-bit

When I compile my SharePoint 2007 solution on a 64-bit machine in Release mode and the platform set to AnyCPU or x86 I get the following error:

An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll.

When I use .Net Reflector on Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll it says the platform is set to x64. So I change my settings to Release mode and the platform to x64 and get the same error.

The strange thing is when I change Release to debug, It complies. Can anyone explain this?

I would prefer compiling with the settings Release/AnyCPU if its possible. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks

p.s. I also asked the question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/21d14405-ca6f-4503-b416-f56bfb27168b/

Answer (score 0):

I too have experienced this same issue, for me it seemed that my changes to the build configuration weren't actually taking. After several attempts at saving, reopening project, choosing build/rebuild, I was able to get it functioning after choosing "Clean" from the build options.